# unable to connect wifi using "wifi_configuration" package in flutter

Tags: flutter, package, wifi

In My new project

[image: My project]

I am using the "Wifi_configuration" package to connect wifi through my app itself.
But i am unable to connect to wifi using the "Wifi_configuration" package.
I had added all the permissions also which are required for it in the android manifest file
But every time it says unable to connect to wifi and unable to enable "WIFI"
Even though all code is proper I have copied it from the flutter API page itself.
Even the wifi is already connected then also it is not showing in wifi status that is already connected

Comment: Can you also AndroidManifest as well?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to connect from android 10, with android 9 or less there were no problems, the [Wifi](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi) package works fine. For android 10 the package that worked well for me is [flutter_wifi_connect](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wifi_connect), i use the secureWifi method.

```
Future<Null> connection(ssid) async {
await FlutterWifiConnect.connectToSecureNetwork(ssid, password)
    .then((value) {
  this.cardConectionState = value;
  notifyListeners();
  print(value);
});
```

in all the AndroidManifest files i put this permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

I hope I have helped

Answer (score 1):

The "Wifi_configuration" package will not work as android has changed the way of directly connecting to wifi using ssid and password by third party app.

So to check the connected wifi status like ssid you can use "connectivity" flutter package.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative package that can connect to Wi-Fi networks? Or just check the status like 'connectivity' does.

Comment: i have tried similar package called "wifi" also none of them were working, currenlty android has updated the way to connect to the wifi from any third party apps, so you need permissions like location etc, still you want to connect to the wifi from your android app check out link 

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346964/connect-to-wifi-programmatically-not-working-for-android-marshmallow)